# How do you find questions that contain your favorite tags on stack overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

I recently joined Stack overflow and am having trouble finding questions in my area of expertise. I have added quite a few tags to my Favorite Tags group but I don't see very many questions containing those tags when I browse your site. I can usually find relevant questions by clicking on one particular tag and looking at the recent questions containing that tag but since there are many tags that are synonyms of each other this isn't always practical.

Comment: If they're truly synonyms of each other then the same questions will show up under each.

Answer (score 3):

We already have that, it's called [StackExchange filters](https://stackexchange.com/filters/).

Here you can create your own filters, based on tags or use the 'Favorite Tags' filter to be automatic in sync with all your favorite tags on all StackExchange networks.

#### Creating your own filter

Imagine you have the [html](/questions/tagged/html) and [css](/questions/tagged/css) filters marked as favorites. To filter them, click on the 'new filter' button. Then answer the `I'd like to include...` question with `Just questions tagged with the ... tag` and use `[html] or [css]` as value of that text box.

Then click on `Just these sites` to select StackOverflow.com.

Now click on 'Save Changes' and your filter is created. You can also sign up for email notifications.

---

Another way of doing this is to just create a bookmark to a search on SO on `[html] or [css]`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html+or+css

Comment: I tried to but [html] or [css] as a filter on StackExchange it said "No sites found with the "[html] or [css]" tag." I tried a couple variations of that as well and I cant create a filter with two tags.

Answer (score 2):

- You can click on a tag to see other questions with the same tag.
- You can enter a query in the search bar that includes one or more tag names in brackets, like `[foo][bar]`. You can also include keywords (not in brackets) to further narrow the search.
- You can enter tags under "Favorite Tags" to highlight questions with your favorite tags in the [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) lists.

Comment: `[foo][bar]` means all questions tagged with [tag:foo] **and** [tag:bar]

Comment: @WouterJ Right -- I didn't mean to imply otherwise. If you want OR it'd be `[foo] or [bar]`.

Comment: I know how to select favorite tags, but most of the questions in the unanswered questions list aren't in my tags. Is there some way to tell it not to display items that don't have at least one of your tags in it.

Answer (score 0):

I keep a bookmark such as:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+or+html+or+css+or+javascript+or+jquery+or+actionscript-3+or+ruby+or+regex

To find questions I can answer quickly.

The `OR` operator is extremely helpful.

(the search term would be `[java] OR [html] OR [css] OR...`)